# I can't dispatch an action inside my effect

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I can't dispatch my action in my effect file. It works when I return data instead of loadFilesSuccess().

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType} from "@ngrx/effects";
import { RequestService } from "../services/request.service";
import { loadFiles,loadFilesSuccess, increment } from "../actions/files.actions";
import { mergeMap, map, catchError, exhaustMap } from "rxjs/operators";
import * as FilesActions from '../actions/files.actions';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
    })
export class RequestEffects {
    constructor(private actions$: Actions, private requestService: RequestService) { }

    sendFile$ = createEffect(() => {
        return this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(loadFiles),
            exhaustMap((action) => {
               return this.requestService.sendDatas(action.data).pipe(
                    map((data: any) => {
                        console.log(data)
                        return loadFilesSuccess()
                    }),
                    catchError((error) => {
                        console.log(error)
                        return error
                    })
                )
            })
        )
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can dispatch an action in an effect but it isn't recommended.
For more info see https://ngrx.io/guide/eslint-plugin/rules/no-dispatch-in-effects.